# Haskell pointfree programming

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand pointfree programming in Haskell and I questions on some examples, because I don't really understand the explanation given when the errors occur.

1) I have a cycle function defined below:

```
myCycle :: [a] -> [a]
myCycle = foldr (++) [] . repeat
```

Why does `myCycle = foldr (++) [] $ repeat` not work?

2) Add every element of a list with 2 then add with another list

```
sum :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
sum s = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ s
```

Why does the function has the same result with `sum s = zipWith (+) $ map (+ 2) s` and why does `sum l1 l2 = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ l1 $ l2` not work

Comment: if you want to *cheat*  you can always use [Pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/)

Comment: I used it at a moment but I also want to understand what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's list all types:

```
foldr  :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
(++)   :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[]     :: [a]
repeat ::  a  -> [a]
(.)    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
($)    :: (a -> b) -> a -> b

foldr (++)          :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
foldr (++) []       ::        [[a]] -> [a]
```

Now, as you can see, `($)` doesn't change the type at all. It's just so that its fixity makes sure that you can use it instead of parentheses. Let's see how they differ:

```
($) (foldr (++) []) :: [[a]]             -> [a]
(.) (foldr (++) []) :: (b -> [[a]]) -> b -> [a]
```

Since `repeat` has type `c -> [c]`, it doesn't work with `($)`. It sure does with `(.)`, since `c ~ [a]` works fine.

So always keep in mind that `($)` doesn't do anything on its own. It merely changes the precedence/fixity. Also, it sometimes helps if you use prefix notation instead of infix if you try to understand/come to pointfree code:

```
sum l1 l2 = zipWith (+) (map (+2) l1) l2
          = zipWith (+) (map (+2) l1) $ l2
          = ($) (zipWith (+) (map (+2) l1)) l2
-- get rid  of both ($) and l2:
sum l1    = zipWith (+) (map (+2) l1)
          = (zipWith (+)) ((map (+2)) l1)
          = f (g l1)                           -- f = zipWith (+), g = map (+2) 
          = (f . g) l1
          = (zipWith (+) . (map (+2)) l1       -- substitute f and g again
          = zipWith (+) . (map (+2) $ l1
-- get rid of $ and l1:
sum       = zipWith (+) . map (+2)
```

Comment: Can you explain how did you get `((.) (zipWith (+) (map (+2))) l1` from `zipWith (+) (map (+2) l1)` ?

Comment: `f (g x)` is `(f . g) x`. If you add additional parentheses, you'll see that `f = zipWith (+)` and `g = map (+2)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the signatures in GHCi you get

```
Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Prelude> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

This shows that the dot operator operates on functions while the dollar operator is just a strange version of the normal function application (it allows you to write e.g. `f (g (h x))` as `f $ g $ h $ x`).

In your `mycycle` example `foldr (++) []` has signature `[[a]] -> [a]` and `repeat` has `a -> [a]`. So when typing `foldr (++) [] $ repeat` Haskell tries to match the function signature `a -> [a]` with the first argument of the `foldr` expression which is `[[a]]`, a list of lists. This fails and gives an error. The dot operator actually expects a function and everything is fine.

In your second example, `sum s = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ s` is equivalent to `sum = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2)`. Type inference regards `zipWith (+)` as a unary function returning a unary function and is able to match it to the argument expected by the dot operator. So here the functions are first composed and then applied to `s`. In `sum s = zipWith (+) $ map (+ 2) s` there is no composition, just application: first `map (+ 2)` is applied to `s` and then `zipWith (+)` is applied to the result.

The point of pointfree programming is to use less function application and more function composition.

Answer (score 2):

`myCycle = foldr (++) [] $ repeat` is equivalent to `myCycle z = (foldr (++) [] $ repeat) z`.

`(x $ y) z` is equal to `(x y) z`; `(x . y) z` is equal to `x (y z)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to gain insight on these things in haskell is to just manually expand things out, based on their definitions.

```
(f . g) = \x -> f (g x)
f $ x   = f x
```

So, whenever we see `(f . g)`, we can replace it with `\x -> f (g x)`.  and when we see `f $ x`, we can replace it with `f x`.  let's see where this takes us!

```
myCycle = foldr (++) [] . repeat
```

Hm, let's expand out the definition of `.`:

```
myCycle = \x -> foldr (++) [] (repeat x)
myCycle x = foldr (++) [] (repeat x)
```

Sweet, this basically does exactly what we'd want it to do.  Concatenate a list of repeating x's.

Now, let's see if you had done `$`:

```
myCycle = foldr (++) [] $ repeat
```

That becomes:

```
myCycle = foldr (++) [] repeat
```

That's nice and all, but this doesn't make any sense.  the third argument of `foldr` should be a list, but you gave it a function (`repeat`).  `repeat` is definitely not a list, so this whole affair is kind of silly.

We can try the same thing here:

```
sum s = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ s
sum s = (zipWith (+) . map (+ 2)) s
sum s = zipWith (+) (map (+ 2) s)    -- (f . g) x = f (g x)
```

And look at the other formulation:

```
sum s = zipWith (+) $ map (+ 2) s
sum s = (zipWith (+)) (map (+ 2) s)
sum s = zipWith (+) (map (+ 2) s)      -- redundant parentheses
```

and...they're the same thing!

Let's try seeing what the last one does:

```
sum l1 l2 = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ l1 $ l2
sum l1 l2 = zipWith (+) . map (+ 2) $ (l1 l2)
```

Oops...you're trying to do `l1 l2`, or apply `l1` as if it were a function.  That doesn't make any sense.  `l1` is a list, not a function.  So, already here you can see why this is nonsense :)