# Haskell Function Composition - (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> d)

Tags: haskell, lambda, function-composition, pointfree

I would like to learn how the following would be done in point-free:

```
withinBounds :: [Int] -> Bool
withinBounds xs = (all (>= 0) xs) && (all (<= 8) xs)
```

I understand that it is superior to write it this way for readability/sanity's sake, but I'd like to learn more about how I can compose functions. I've been scratching my head as to how I can do this. 
The whole (expanded?) type signature is

```
[Int] -> ([Int] -> Bool) -> ([Int] -> Bool) -> (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
```

The type signature of the composition I'm trying to get to is

```
(a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> d)
```

I wrote the following as notes in a bastard-lambda form. If there is a way to somewhat simplify the problem with the lambda calculus, it'd be great if that could be explained too:

```
\L@[] ->  \f1@([] -> Bool) -> \f2@([] -> Bool) -> \f3@(Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> f3.(f1.L).(f2.L)
```

In the above, `.` is application, `@` is capturing (so f3 is another name for (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)). 
Many thanks.

Edit: I know this is not the most optimal or reusable code, and I know turning this into point-free makes it worse in terms of readability etc. To clarify, I am asking how I can turn it into point-free **because I want to learn more about haskell and composition**.

Edit2: [A really good SO answer on point-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell?rq=1)

Comment: Your `withinBounds` is not composable, it is better to write the check for a single element and then call `all` on that. In fact, I would probably just inline `all withinBounds` where withinBounds is for a single element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tell-tale sign of the function not being composable? (for example the input being required in multiple places in the body?)

Comment: @MIJOTHY: usually, if the type is more general, it's likely more reusable, e.g. `withinBounds :: Ord e => (e, e) -> e -> Bool; withinBounds (a,b) x = a <= x && x <= b`. Now your original function is simply `all (withinBounds (0,8))`. Furthermore, I can use this as predicate for a filter: `filter (withinBounds (4,100)) [1..103]`.

Comment: Yeah I can understand how general = more reusable, but I was wondering if there is a certain way to tell whether a function can be written in point-free (using the composition operator) or not. Perhaps my usage of 'composable' is wrong. So to rephrase the question with the more general version you wrote, could I write `withinBounds (a,b) x = a <= x && x <= b` in point-free?

Comment: @MIJOTHY: Yes, but you don't want to. `uncurry ((. flip (<=)) . ap . ((&&) .) . (<=))`. At the end, code is not only read by a computer, but by a human. The point-free version is not only longer, but also harder to grasp than the original one.

Comment: @Zeta I did mention that I realise it's not the best way to do it, but I'd like to know the process as I'm trying to learn about composition. Apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: @Zeta How did you arrive at your point-free solution? Is there a method for doing so, or it comes down to "feel"?

Comment: @MIJOTHY: Oh, sorry, I forgot to tell you. There is the `pointfree` package on Hackage, lambdabot on `#haskell`, and http://pointfree.io. That being said, I usually move parameters around till I end up with a eta-reducible function, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36542287/1139697.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing an end-run around the whole question, I think I would probably write it this way:

```
import Data.Ix
withinBounds = all (inRange (0, 8))
```

Of course, that's punting a bit, since then one would naturally ask how to implement `inRange` in a pointfree way. If you absolutely couldn't use `inRange`, then I would implement it inline this way:

```
withinBounds = all (liftA2 (&&) (>=0) (<=8))
```

This uses the reader applicative to supply a single argument to two functions. `liftA2` is your requested combining function, though with arguments flipped:

```
requested :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> d)
liftA2    :: (b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> (a -> d)
```

Comment: Oh I see! So since `liftA2 f a b = fmap f a <*> b` and `f <$> x = fmap f x`, `liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b` this connects to @Safareli's answer nicely.

Comment: And because for ((->) r) `fmap = (.)`, it can also be written `withinBounds = (&&) . (all (>= 0)) <*> (all (<= 8))`

Answer (score 9):

You could use the fact that function is Applicative.
and write `withinBounds` this way:

```
withinBounds = pure (&&) <*> all (>= 0) <*> all (<= 8)
```

Or this  way:

```
withinBounds = (&&) <$> all (>= 0) <*> all (<= 8)
```

You could read about Applicatives [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810889/functions-as-applicative-functors-haskell-lyah)

Comment: Why was my comment deleted/why has it disappeared?

Comment: have no idea :/ yesterday it had two upvotes, one from me

Answer (score 9):

There's a class that's basically dedicated for point-free compositions<sup>†</sup> with multiple “channels”: [`Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Arrow). If you're determined to make everything point-free then this is IMO the way to go. The ugly bit about this is that you constantly need to uncurry functions:

```
import Control.Arrow

withinBounds = all (>=0) &&& all (<=8) >>> uncurry (&&)
```

How this works is best understood with a diagram:

```
      all (>=0) ────
       ╱                ╲
──── &&&            >>>  uncurry (&&) ───
       ╲                ╱
      all (<=8) ────
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>`Arrow` works in a generalised setting; not just for **Hask**-functions but for any suitable category. But it's useful enough to apply it just to functions.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, the diagram really helps too. I'll do some reading about arrow.

Answer (score -2):

Notice that x<=8 if and only if 8-x>=0, so, using only prelude, we can write

```
withinBounds :: [Int] -> Bool
withinBounds = all $ (all (>=0)) . (zipWith (+) [0,8]) . (zipWith (*) [1,-1]) . (replicate 2)
```

Basically I just map `x` to `[x,x]` then to `[x,8-x]` and then I require these two to be >=0 simultaneously.

Of course, as pointed out in the comments, you can also make `a,b` parameters so as to reuse them later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the down-voter care to explain the reason for the down vote, so that I can improve upon it? In fact this trick is quite useful in other similar tasks as well, and does not require such  advanced knowledge as other answers do.

Comment: Well, OP said in the question body that the readability is not the concern here: he just wants to know how to write this in a point-less way.  Also, I added an explanation to go through the process of this function. Maybe I shall explain more? In any case, thanks for the reply.